# Unable to load Hive table with ROW FORMAT DELIMITED from spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to load csv file with '~' delimited to Hive external table.

Below is the code snippet in spark scala

```
scala > val df = spark.read
                          .options(Map("delimiter"->"~"))
                          .csv(s"file://${textFile}")
        
scala> df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto(s"schema.parquet_table")
```

Now I a getting the below error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.ParquetHiveRecord
```

The table is created as below.

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0007'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

Please suggest what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with cast from text to parquet. Try creating a sample table like mytable without serde properties but just 'stored as parquet' and check if insert overwrite works.